# Why isn't Object safe to use after IsValid(Object) returned true?

Tags: c++, access-violation, unreal-engine4

I have the following function:

```
void AddActor(AActor* Actor)
{
    if (!IsValid(Actor)) { return; }    

    if (Actor->IsA(ACertainActor::StaticClass()))
    { 
        //...
    }
}
```

It gets passed some valid and some invalid `Actor`-pointers (`Actors` that are pending destroy or are already destroyed).

And according to the code documentation `IsValid()` returns `true` if the object is usable:

```
/**
* Test validity of object
*
* @param    Test            The object to test
* @return   Return true if the object is usable: non-null and not pending kill
*/
```

But it crashes at `if (Actor->IsA(ACertainActor::StaticClass()))` throwing an access violation:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF868B56895 (UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll) in UE4Editor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

I would expect that `IsValid(Object)` checks whether `Object` is `nullptr`, the engine knows `Object` and if it does checks whether is it pending destroy. 
So after `IsValid(Object)` returned true, `Object` should be usable.

Is that not how it works?

Is there any other way to check whether a pointer points to a valid object that can be used?

Comment: The documentation doesn't clearly explain the requirements before calling `IsValid`. But presumably, your code doesn't meet them. I surmise the pointer must either be nullptr, point to a valid `AActor` or point to an invalid `AActor` (pending kill).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, from your exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF868B56895 (UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll) in UE4Editor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

in clearly states that this pointer is not nullptr, it is of value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. So `IsValid` works as written in docs:

> Return true if the object is usable: non-null and not pending kill

You should initialize your pointer to `nullptr`.